# Stripe - how call confirmCardSetup without cardElement?

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using my own form for the credit card creedentials.

I was trying to follow the instructions here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#storing-payment-methods

Based on the [Stripe's instructions](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method), you can pass cardElement or Card object. I would like to create the Card object myself, but I can't find which info does that object have:

```
cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
        clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: cardElement, //or Card object
                billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
            }
        }
    );

    if (error) {
        // Display "error.message" to the user...
    } else {
        // The card has been verified successfully...
    }
});
```

Not clear if I should simply use specific ids in my inputs, and then simply pass the form there, but I can't find that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the details of the Card object [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card), which looks like this:

```
card: {
  number: '4242424242424242',
  exp_year: '2024',
  exp_month: '02',
  cvc: '123',
}
```

However, using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) is strongly recommended.

It's important to be aware of the [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) implications of this. It is your responsibility to make sure your implementation is compliant, and you will be required to provide additional documentation for your business.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to use the Elements, it's just that I want to fill the card details via code, as I would like to use my own form. THe client completes my form and when click on "save" I make the call to Stripe using Elements, but I just don't know if there is a way to include card data in that object via JS

Comment: That's not a recommended flow and will have PCI implications you need to address. Elements is specifically the form inputs for data covered by PCI (card number, cvc etc) and you cannot programmatically interact with them to fill or inspect values. These are handled within a Stripe-hosted `iframe` so that you cannot access them by design.